# How to query based on association values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm not sure how to write this query in rails.  I have a Person class and a PersonEmailAddress class where the Person class has a has_many person_email_addresses, inverse_of: :person.

The person class has an owner which is an instance of a User class.  The User class has a company_id on it.  So, the relationships would visually look something like...

```
Company - id property
    User
        Person
            PersonEmailAddress - email property
```

I need to write a query that looks for a matching record where the email matches a record in the PersonEmailAddress table and the company id matches a record in the Company table.  Aside from writing raw sql, can anyone suggest how I can chain this all together?  Thanks.

Comment: Would this work? 

   `company = Company.find( id_query )`  `person = User.where(company_id: company).first.person`
`person.find_by_email( email_query )`

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get it done in one query.  This "looks" like 3 if I'm understanding it correctly.  I know that down the road this functionality is going to be changing, so I'm rethinking the idea of just doing it in sql for now to get it done.